# Find point on the Spline Curve in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, syncfusion-chart

I am having some discrete points, by using which I can plot spline curve(Syncfusion chart) in flutter. But now I have to find the point on that curve i.e. by giving values of x, I need value of y. I am stucked here and don't have any algorithm to apply for that. How did they make graph using discrete point ? There should be some algorithm which can be applied here and get those point.
Please help me out
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please add more detail with your code.

Comment: @pskink The curve is plotted using the discrete points using the spline chart of syncfusion SFchartseries

Comment: @developer I need all point from spline curve, which is plotted from discrete points

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am here with a great solution to this problem, So The idea goes like if we have n points for equilibrium data, then we will assume a polynomial of order n-1(For eg. no. of points on equilibrium curve to be 3 then the polynomial should be quadratic of form y= Ax²+Bx+C). Now as we have 3 variables(A, B, C), then to solve this equation we need 3 equations in terms of A, B and C. These equations are obtained by putting the equilibrium data points, in this case 3 points so we will get 3  equations. These three equations can be solved by using Cramer's rule. After solving the equation we will get the equation of the curve.
The equation thus obtained will be more accurate and as cramer's rule can be obtained to any number of equations, then we can easily obtain polynomial equation of any order.This method is quite big and will be time taking to apply.
This will give you the curve for a given number of points